# How to check url in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am creating and hiding a certain navigation in Laravel. The navigation uses **nav tag**

This is my current code:

```
@if (Request::url() === 'login')
    <nav></nav>
@endif
```

**Problem**: I only want the  tag to appear if it's not in LOGIN page.

Please help me fix the code above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Give this a try: `Route::is('login')`

Comment: Hi @MateiMihai , I tried your code. It has no effect...

Answer (score 2):

This should work with your code.

`! means IS NOT.`

```
@if (!Request::url() === 'login')
    <nav></nav>
@endif
```

So this code will run when the url isn't 'login'.

---

You could also use `named routes`. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes)

```
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'ControllerName@methodName']);
```

Than you can check if the page is `login`. You can do it like this:

```
@if(Route::is('login'))
    This is the route 'login'
@endif
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

make your login route as follows:

```
Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'ControllerName@methodName']);
```

Now on view page just do as follows:

```
@if(Route::is('login'))
  <nav></nav>
@endif
```

This will show the 'nav' tag when route is not login
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

the '!' means NOT, so the nav shows when the url is not login.

```
@if (!Request::is('login')) 
        <nav>I Am a menu item</nav>
@endif
```